# How to generate a random matrix whose eigenvalues are less than one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I generate a random matrix. It has this general form:

$$\mathbf{B}=\left[ \matrix{ \mathbf{A}_1&\mathbf{A}_2&\ldots&\mathbf{A}_{p-1}&\mathbf{A}_p \\ 
\mathbf{I}_M&\mathbf{I}_M&\ldots&\mathbf{I}_M&\mathbf{O}_M \\
 \vdots &\vdots &\ddots& \vdots& \vdots\\
 \mathbf{I}_M&\mathbf{I}_M&\ldots&\mathbf{I}_M&\mathbf{O}_M \\ } \right]:(pM \times pM)$$

in which $\mathbf{A}_i$ is $M \times M$ for $i=1,\ldots,p$ and $\mathbf{O}_M$ ($M\times M$) and $\mathbf{I}_M$ ($M\times M$) are zero and identity matrices.

The elements of $\mathbf{A}_i$ are random (they are from a multivariate normal distribution). The eigenvalues of $\mathbf{B}$ should be less than one and I don't want to repeat random number generation process until this happens. I want to change some elements of a generated matrix (whose at least one of its eigenvalues is larger than one) so that all eigenvalues become less than one. Is there any way to do so?

(I think I should answer this question: If I change the $B(i,j)$, how will eigenvalues of $B$ be affected? But I don't know the answer).

edit:
I have this idea: What if I generate a set of random eigenvalues and then generate my matrix based on them. I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you mean eigenvalues in the range $[0,1]$, otherwise $-B$ would do in case all eigenvalues of $B$ are positive...

Comment: in fact the eigenvalues in the the unit circle, since there is the possibility of complex numbers.

Comment: The pattern isn't quite clear -- are all the lower matrices $\mathbf I_M$ except $\mathbf O_M$ in the last column? Also, I think you need to say something about the type of modification you'd like -- in what sense should the resulting matrix be close to the original randomly generated $\mathbf B$? One option would be to just scale $\mathbf B$ down.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks. I edited the pattern. You are right; If I define $\mathbf{C=B}/10$, then its eigenvalues will be $1/10$-th of $\mathbf{B}$. But is there a way to change the minimum number of elements?

Comment: @Ron: I'd be surprised if it's tractable to find the minimal number of elements to change.

Comment: @Ron: I'm confused. Since the eigenvalues of $B$ may be complex, do you mean you want to make the *moduli* of the eigenvalues smaller than 1, **meanwhile** the modified entries still follow a normal distribution?

Comment: @user1551; yes. Is there a way to change some of its elements in such a way that its distribution is still multivariate normal with previous parameters, but the eigenvalues ($a+bi$) are in the unit circle ($a^2+b^2<1$)?

Comment: I've been beating my head against the wall trying to do a similar thing. My application is ensuring Bayesian VAR results are stationary in a MCMC, which I think is a slightly different set up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to your question, but here are some thoughts.

If your normal distribution is able to generate a $B$ whose spectral radius is $\ge1$, then any procedure to modify $B$ to make its spectral radius less than one would clearly result in non-conformance to the normal distribution. So, I assume that you want to modify $B$ such that it follows a conditional distribution of normal distribution.

This seems to me a difficult problem, but the difficulty goes beyond that. In fact, **when $p$ and $M$ are large, any such procedure would necessarily mean that you are drawing samples from the tails of normal distribution**, i.e. you are mostly using extreme events as samples.

Here is an explanation. Let $v=(v_1^T,v_2^T,\ldots,v_n^T)^T$ be an eigenvector of $B$. If $v$ corresponds to the zero eigenvalue, then the equation $Bv=0$ means
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 & \ldots & A_{p-1} & A_p\\
I & I & \ldots & I & 0
\end{pmatrix}v=0
$$
The rank of the matrix on the LHS is almost surely $2M$, so its null space is  $(p-2)M$-dimensional and $B$ almost surely has $2M$ nonzero eigenvalues.

Now, suppose $\lambda$ is a nonzero eigenvalue of $B$. From $Bv=\lambda v$, we get
\begin{align}
A_1v_1 + \sum_{i=2}^p A_pv_p &= \lambda v_1,\\
v_1 + v_2+v_3+\ldots+v_{p-1} &= \lambda v_2,\\
v_1 + v_2+v_3+\ldots+v_{p-1} &= \lambda v_3,\\
&\vdots\\
v_1 + v_2+v_3+\ldots+v_{p-1} &= \lambda v_p.
\end{align}
In other words, $v_2=v_3=\ldots=v_p=$ some vector $u$, $v_1 = [\lambda-(p-2)]u$ and
\begin{align}
A_1[\lambda-(p-2)]u + \sum_{i=2}^p A_pu = \lambda [\lambda-(p-2)]u,\\
\textrm{i.e. }\quad
C_\lambda u:=\left(\lambda^2 I - \lambda [(p-2) I + A_1] + \left[(p-2)A_1 - \sum_{i=2}^p A_p\right]\right)u = 0.
\end{align}
Let $q(\lambda) = \det\,C_\lambda$. Then $q(\lambda)=0$ is a degree-$2M$ polynomial equation in $\lambda$. The sum $S$ of its $2M$ roots is the coefficient of $\lambda^{2M-1}$ in $q(\lambda)$, i.e. $S = \mathrm{trace}\left((p-2) I + A_1\right) = M(p-2)+\mathrm{trace}\,A_1$. In order that these $2M$ roots all have moduli smaller than $1$, $|S|$ must be smaller than $2M$. Hence $\left|(p-2)+\frac{\mathrm{trace}\,A_1}{M}\right|<2$. When $M$ is large, however $\frac{\mathrm{trace}\,A_1}{M}$ will be distributed around the mean $\mu$ of the normal distribution, with variance of order $O(1/M)$. Since $\left|(p-2)+\mu\right|\ge2$ when $p$ is large, we conclude that, when both $M$ and $p$ are large, the condition $|S|<2$ is satisfied only when $\frac{\mathrm{trace}\,A_1}{M}$ is an extreme value.

Comment: thanks a lot. I think I should have mentioned that the matrix is square.

Comment: @Ron: What do you mean? I didn't say that $B$ is not square. I thought it was square all along.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'm working on it. thanks